# Anything external as fast as an array? So I don't need to re-load arrays each time I run scripts

Tags: ruby

While I am developing my application I need to do tons of math over and over again, tweaking it and running again and observing results.

The math is done on arrays that are loaded from large files. Many megabytes. Not very large but the problem is each time I run my script it first has to load the files into arrays. Which takes a long time.

I was wondering if there is anything external that works similarly to arrays, in that I can know the location of data and just get it. And that it doesn't need to reload everything.

I don't know much about databases except that they seem to not work the way I need to. They aren't ordered and always need to search through everything. It seems. Still a possibility is in-memory databases?

If anyone has a solution it would be great to hear it.

Side question - isn't it just possible to have user entered scripts that my ruby program runs so I can have the main ruby program run indefinitely? I still don't know anything about user entered options and how that would work though.

Comment: try the database reproach, it usually is the fastest option, databases are organised and ordered by definition by structure and indexes, start wit a no installation required like Sqlite and if that is not up to your needs you can upgrade easily, the sollution of Catnapper requires each time to load your file entirely to array, a database doesn't have to

Comment: as to your side qustion, better make it an apart question but search first, i have seen similar questions

Comment: As for databases, a database is designed for rapid random access to the records. If you want to retrieve the data in an order, then tell the database the order you want it to use. Also, if it seems slow then tell it how to index the data and it will be fast. In-memory is simple if you use SQLite. Check out [the examples](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) at the beginning of the Sequel gem's documentation for ideas of how easy it is to do this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Marshal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html):

```
# save an array to a file
File.open('array', 'w') { |f| f.write Marshal.dump(my_array) }

# load an array from file
my_array = File.open('array', 'r') { |f| Marshal.load(f.read) }
```

Your OS will keep the file cached between saves and loads, even between runs of separate processes using the data.

Comment: "Your OS *will* keep the file cached" should be "Your OS *might* keep the file cached". What the OS does will vary depending on the available disk cache size and amount of activity on the machine. Counting on the data being in the cache, especially between runs of an separate process, is likely to lead to disappointment unless they are running sequentially and little else is happening. Marshalling only controls the format of the data being saved but it doesn't have any magical powers controlling caching.

Comment: @tin man: Correct.  But it's a good bet for data sets that fit in memory, and the machine is otherwise not doing much of anything else.  This method is straightforward and easy to implement for the programmer, especially compared to database.  If the whole data set will be iterated, and the set fits in memory, the database offers no advantage.  Keep it as simple as possible, but no simpler, in other words.